# ORA-00907: Missing Right Parenthesis on a left join of two subqueries

Tags: sql, oracle

It's been a little while since I've messed with SQL and I'm picking it back up for a course. I need to create a table of table name, column name, constraint name, and constraint type for all tables with my user, but every time I try, I'm getting a missing right parenthesis error. Here's my code so far:

```
SELECT table_name, column_name, constraint_name, constraint_type 
FROM     
(
     SELECT a.table_name, a.column_name, a.constraint_name FROM all_cons_columns AS a
     WHERE a.owner = '[my_user]'
     AND a.table_name NOT LIKE 'APEX%'
     AND a.constraint_name NOT LIKE 'BIN%'
     ORDER BY a.table_name
) AS x
LEFT JOIN
(
     SELECT b.constraint_name, b.constraint_type FROM all_constraints AS b
     WHERE b.owner = '[my_user]'
     AND b.table_name NOT LIKE 'APEX%'
     AND b.constraint_name NOT LIKE 'BIN%'
     ORDER BY b.constraint_name
) AS y
ON x.constraint_name = y.constraint_name
```

SQL Developer says it's at the "AS a" in line 4 but I'm not finding much information scouring the web. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: if you remove the AS keyword after your table (for the alias) that may work.  So just FROM all_cons_columns a  for example.

Comment: Also remove the `ORDER BY` from the subqueries.  Not a syntax issue but does not do anything useful either.

Comment: Oops, I copied my code with the ORDER BY in it but had already removed it. I've tried removing the AS a and AS b and that error goes away, and then flags on at AS x as "SQL statement not properly ended". hmmm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you remove AS it works:

```
   SELECT table_name, column_name, x.constraint_name, constraint_type
      FROM (SELECT a.table_name, a.column_name, a.constraint_name
              FROM all_cons_columns  a
             WHERE a.owner = '[my_user]'
               AND a.table_name NOT LIKE 'APEX%'
               AND a.constraint_name NOT LIKE 'BIN%'
             ORDER BY a.table_name) x
              LEFT JOIN (SELECT b.constraint_name, b.constraint_type
                    FROM all_constraints b
                   WHERE b.owner = '[my_user]'
                     AND b.table_name NOT LIKE 'APEX%'
                     AND b.constraint_name NOT LIKE 'BIN%'
                   ORDER BY b.constraint_name) y
          ON x.constraint_name = y.constraint_name
```

but I suppose this query might be shorter and without left join, because it's always matches:

```
select x.table_name,
       x.column_name,
       x.constraint_name,
       y.constraint_type
  from all_cons_columns x
  join all_constraints y
    on x.constraint_name = y.constraint_name
 where x.owner = '[my_user]'
   and x.owner = y.owner
   and x.table_name NOT LIKE 'APEX%'
   and x.constraint_name NOT LIKE 'BIN%'
 order by x.table_name, x.constraint_name
```

Comment: I don't think `constraint_name` is a unique key for `all_constraints`, you'll probably need to add `and x.owner = y.owner` to the join. But otherwise nice.

Comment: Thank you, kfinity, I'm absolutely agree with you. I've corrected the query.

Comment: Wonderful, thank y'all! Definitely need to work on my simplicity of queries

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle SQL, the `AS` keyword can be used for column aliases but not for table aliases.

This is fine:

```
SELECT dummy AS x FROM dual
```

This will produce "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended":

```
SELECT dummy FROM dual AS x
```

Or in a nested subquery it will produce "ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis", as you initially encountered:

```
 SELECT * FROM (SELECT dummy FROM dual AS x)
```

To alias a table, simply leave out the `AS`. This works:

```
SELECT dummy FROM dual x
```

(As a side note, while AS is allowed for column aliases, it is not required.)